# Stuck in uploading java web service to server

Tags: java, android, web-services, xmlpullparser

I have created a WebService in NetBeans, and am using it in Android.

On the localhost it works fine, but when testing for deploying to server it gives an Exception:

`"org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception:expected START_TAG"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well the exception seems to indicate that a start tag is missing - do you have the web service tags wrapped around your content?

Sometimes permissions can be different when testing locally rather than remotely. It can also be different depending on how you're testing it - for example, if you're testing in a web browser, missing tags can often be fixed automatically by the browser so that the page can be displayed - this isn't the case with some stricter XML parsing libraries.

If you could post some code, we might be able to help solve your actual problem rather than guessing what's wrong.